# EA Model Relations- Where are stored?

Tags: c#, api, enterprise-architect

Our team work on a big shared model.
Now we would like to divide the shared model to smaller units:

We can't export the packages as XMLs since there are relations between the packages and elements. Each package should be exported with all its relations.

How can I find all relations of a package and an element? Do **all** the relations stored in t_connectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Most* of the relations in Enterprise Architect are stored in `t_connector`
Some however (such as `tranformed from`) are stored in `t_xref`.

The safest and easiest way to split up a model into smaller parts is to make a complete copy of the model and delete what you don't need.

Comment: Exactly. For example all "Dependency" relations:

select (select Name from t_object where t_object.Object_ID = t_connector.Start_Object_ID) as obj1, (select Name from t_object where t_object.Object_ID = t_connector.End_Object_ID) as obj2, Start_Object_ID, End_Object_ID, * from t_connector where Connector_Type = "Dependency"

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, XML Exports wouldn't get you all the inter-dependencies, however have you considered creating a RAS storage for such sharing. RAS, is a relatively newer concept in EA, can be effectively used if you intend to break a larger repository into smaller ones with all its interdependencies.

Going the DB way will be very difficult and hard to maintain.

Comment: Thannks for the information. Why RAS sharing is better than Version Control with EA?